# Update values on multi level nested Object with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, session-storage

I have an Object on sessionStorage for which I need to update values on user input. I am able to update at the root of the Object but not the values that are nested on a deeper level.

```
request('http://localhost:7474/graphql/', query).then(data => {...}

sessionStorage.setItem('queryData', JSON.stringify(data));

function update(value){
    let prevData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('queryData'));

    Object.keys(value).forEach(function(val, key){
        prevData[val] = value[val];
    });

    sessionStorage.setItem('queryData', JSON.stringify(prevData));
}

update({ maritalStatus: "single" });
```

So maritalStatus ends up been added and not replaced and I must replace the value:

```
Object: [,...]
   0: {id: "x", maritalStatus: "married"} //want to replace this value here
   maritalStatus: "single"  // this is where the value is been written
```

Comment: `prevData` is `{id: "x", maritalStatus: "married"}`? or what is in that varaible?

Comment: Update on how to build the Object in the first place and set the first sessionStorage Object, prevData is a considerable big Object with multiple nested values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data in storage is an Array. So the way you are updating it like `prevData[val] = value[val];` is adding another property to the array with index of `maritalStatus` and value of `"single"`. The object at index `0` is untouched.

My suggested fix is to also include the `id` in your update call. Then loop through the array in storage and look for the object with the matching id.

Once the id matches update that object, or log if no id matches are found.

```js
let dataInStorage = [{
  id: "x",
  maritalStatus: "married"
}];

function update(updateObj) {
  let prevData = dataInStorage;
  let id = updateObj.id;

  dataInStorage.forEach(function(data) {
    if (data.id === id) {
      Object.keys(updateObj).forEach(function(key, index) {
        data[key] = updateObj[key];
      });
    } else {
      console.log(`did not find object with id: ${id}`);
    }
  });
  console.log(prevData)
  //sessionStorage.setItem('queryData', JSON.stringify(prevData));
}

update({
  id: "x",
  maritalStatus: "single"
});
```